# Kotlin creating Bitmap must not be null

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap

onCreate{
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, Color.TRANSPARENT) 
 }
```

I am trying to create a transparent bitmap like above.  However, it gives me this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BitmapFactory.decodeReso…urces, Color.TRANSPARENT) must not be null
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: You declared `bitmap` as `Bitmap` instead of `Bitmap?`. `decodeResource()` can return `null`, and you need to be able to gracefully handle when that occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @commonWare, either declare `bitmap` nullable:

```
var bitmap: Bitmap?
```

or handle `null` when you call `decodeResource`:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, Color.TRANSPARENT) ?: DEFAULT_BITMAP
```

where `DEFAULT_BITMAP` is a default Bitmap you have created earlier.

And better if you have control over `decodeResource` method, make the return type non nullable and return some default value instead of `null` :

```
fun decodeResource(...): Bitmap {
   .....
   return bitmap ?: DEFAULT_BITMAP // return a default value instead of returning null
}
```

Comment: 'lateinit' modifier is not allowed on properties of nullable types. So Bitmap? cannot be written.